# JUnit5: how to do EJB initialization before all other tests?

Tags: ejb, junit5

Under JUnit4 I had a @ManagedBean class that all my integration tests extended, and boilerplate for EJB was performed only once across all tests beforehand using a @ClassRule (see below). What am I supposed to do to guarantee the before() method runs before all other tests now that @ClassRule is gone? The docs say to make an extension, but extensions are supposed to be stateless, which prevents me from accessing instance variables like `context`.

```
@ManagedBean
public class EJBStuff {

    public static Context context;

    @ClassRule
    public static final ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource() {

         @Override
         protected void before() throws Exception {
            if (context == null) {
            final Properties p = new Properties();
            context = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(p).getContext();
        }
    } 
}
```

If I try to make an extension out of this code, extending BeforeAllCallback and writing a beforeAll method, I get this error on EJBContainer.createEJBContainer():

```
org.apache.openejb.OpenEjbContainer$InvalidApplicationException: 
org.apache.openejb.config.ValidationFailedException: Module failed validation. AppModule(name=)
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible with JUnit 5?

Comment: I don’t know about your specific problem but extensions can have state. You have to use the Store mechanism available through ˋcontext.getStore(..)ˋ.

Comment: I think stores are scoped to a given test or method, but I need to be able to maintain a state across test classes so that any class can access a database utility without recreating the whole EJB container for every test.

Comment: You determine the scope of a store yourself by choosing the appropriate context, or parent context, or root context for creating a store.

Comment: Ah, okay. The challenge that I'm finding is that I need to be able to access the database utility I put in the global store at the beginning of a test class, in a static @BeforeClass method, because the utility itself is a static singleton. But it seems like there's no way for me to access anything put in the store from anything other than the beforeAll and afterAll sort of extension methods, which can never be static. Is there still a way for me to acquire such static values?

Comment: ˋ@BeforeClassˋ is JUnit 4 and will never be called, ˋ@BeforeAllˋ is what Jupiter has instead. Your extension can implement ˋParameterResolverˋ with which you can inject whatever you take from the store into your annotated method.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly it. Thank you!